# How to make search button redirect to search results page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, search

I am a beginner and new to this stuff I have a search form with button type submit I want when I click on that button to open a new window displaying the search results with a url. Please can someone help me with this query ??

> php code :

```
function output_full_screen_search() {      
    
    ?>
<div id="full-screen-search">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="full-screen-search-close">X</button>
        <form role="search" method="get" action="https://hostingstudies.com/" target="_blank" id="full-screen-search-form">
            <div id="full-screen-search-container">
                <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search" id="full-screen-search-input" />
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php


}
```

}

> jquery code :

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    
    // ... display the Full Screen search when:
    // 1. The user focuses on a search field, or
    // 2. The user clicks the Search button
    $( 'form[role=search] input, form[role=search] button' ).on( 'focus, click', function( event ) {
        // Prevent the default action
        //event.preventDefault();
    
        // Display the Full Screen Search
        $( '#full-screen-search' ).addClass( 'open' );
    
        // Focus on the Full Screen Search Input Field
        $( '#full-screen-search input' ).focus();
    } );

    // Hide the Full Screen search when the user clicks the close button
    $( '#full-screen-search button.close' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
        // Prevent the default event
        event.preventDefault();

        // Hide the Full Screen Search
        $( '#full-screen-search' ).removeClass( 'open' );
    } );

} );
```

Comment: 1. add `target="_blank"` to the `<form>` tag. 2. remove `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - or explain how this is related to PHP. Additionally, show your attempts to open that new window

Comment: Do you want the form to go to the address stated in `action=` attribute? If so, remove the `event.preventDefault();` line from the submit button handler, it stops the default behavior of the submit action.

Comment: How to remove the event.preventDefault(); line from the submit button handler ??

Comment: @Don Check the answer I've posted, let me know if it resolved your issue.

Comment: What do you mean `how to remove it`?

Comment: @kabirbaidhya No it doesn't work

Comment: @Chris G  I removed the line event.preventDefault(); and added target="_blank" to the <form> tag but there is no result

Comment: No result? Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tjdfomze/ works fine for me

Comment: @Chris G your jsfiddle works great the problem is that this code works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in my wordpress website ??

Comment: You need to be more specific. "doesn't work" is a useless problem description; what exactly happens when you send the form? Did you look at the console?

Comment: Hey @Chris G you can see the code of your jsfiddle above in the question see If i made any mistake please this code inside a plugin full screen search plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a submit search button that redirects to search results page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052139/how-to-create-a-submit-search-button-that-redirects-to-search-results-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `event.preventDefault();` from your handler, it stops the form submission which is the default behavior for forms.

```
    $( 'form[role=search] input, form[role=search] button' ).on( 'focus, click', function( event ) {
        // Display the Full Screen Search
        $( '#full-screen-search' ).addClass( 'open' );
    
        // Focus on the Full Screen Search Input Field
        $( '#full-screen-search input' ).focus();
    } );
```