# How to create a submit search button that redirects to search results page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a plugin full screen search overlay in my wordpress website but this search form is only working when the user hit enter I want also the user to click a search button and get redirected to search results page when he enters a search term.can you please help me with this query ??

this is the full screen search.php code:

function output_full_screen_search() {

```
    ?>
    <div id="full-screen-search">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="full-screen-search-close">X</button>
        <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" id="full-screen-search-form">
            <div id="full-screen-search-container">
                <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search' ); ?>" id="full-screen-search-input" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
```

this is the js file of the plugin :

// When the document is ready...
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

```
// ... display the Full Screen search when:
// 1. The user focuses on a search field, or
// 2. The user clicks the Search button
$( 'form[role=search] input, form[role=search] button' ).on( 'focus, click', function( event ) {
    // Prevent the default action
    event.preventDefault();

    // Display the Full Screen Search
    $( '#full-screen-search' ).addClass( 'open' );

    // Focus on the Full Screen Search Input Field
    $( '#full-screen-search input' ).focus();
} );

// Hide the Full Screen search when the user clicks the close button
$( '#full-screen-search button.close' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // Prevent the default event
    event.preventDefault();

    // Hide the Full Screen Search
    $( '#full-screen-search' ).removeClass( 'open' );
} );
```

} );

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why my submit search button does not redirect to search results page when I enter a search term and click on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036038/why-my-submit-search-button-does-not-redirect-to-search-results-page-when-i-ente)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change button `type` attribute to `submit`.

Because

```
<button type="button" class="close" id="full-screen-search-close">X</button>
```

is considered as general button.